# Objective-c : How to convert PST to UTC/local time zone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

Am getting time stamp from server as "2015-11-12T03:54:52Z" which is in PST. I want to convert this string to UTC/Local time zone format. I tried in the following way

```
NSDateFormatter *pstFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[pstFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];
[pstFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *pstQUU = [pstFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-11-12T04:03:03Z"];

Original output : 2015-11-12 04:03:03 +0000
Expected output : 2015-11-12 12:03:03 +0000 (UTC)
```

Comment: The server should be using Unix time (UTC) Why would the server express times in PST?

Comment: @DuncanC: Server is sending the PST time.

Comment: The server is sending time strings? Making a server use a particular time zone is bad design. UTC is the standard for exchanging times/dates over the internet.

Comment: @Javeed You are incorrect about the time stamp from the server. It is not in PST. The `Z` at the end of the string clearly indicates that the time stamp is in Zulu time (UTC time). If it really were in PST then it would end with `PST` or `-0800`.

Comment: @DuncanC : Thanks for info on the server timezone. I will update my server team.

Comment: @Javeed It's not an assumption given the facts. The `Z` means it's in UTC time. If the timestamp truly is in PST time then it's a serious bug because you don't slap `Z` on a timestamp that isn't UTC time. Either way there is a serious disconnect and something needs to be fixed. Either the timestamp needs to be formatted properly or your code needs to properly work with the provided UTC timestamp.

Comment: @Avi But the string isn't in "local time". It may be in some specific time but not "local time" . Local time is based on the user's device. The server will always send the timestamp in a specific timezone.

Comment: @Avi Even my R&D told me that 'Z' stands for UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the UTC offset values like this

```
    NSDateFormatter *pstFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *pstTimezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];
    [pstFormatter setTimeZone:pstTimezone];
    [pstFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *pstDate = [pstFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-11-12T04:03:03Z"];

    NSTimeInterval utcSeconds = [pstDate timeIntervalSince1970] - [pstTimezone secondsFromGMT];
    NSDate *utcDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:utcSeconds];
```

Comment: It is working fine with other  formats like CST, EST etc... too

Comment: It makes no sense to set the timezone of the date formatter when you are parsing a string that specifies its own timezone.

Comment: @rmaddy Timezone is only to get the difference from GMT. It has no relationship with Converting a string to Date object.